# golang mysql undefined: sql.Query

Tags: mysql, go

I'm trying to do a golang db query like:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "database/sql"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

var (
    name string
    id int
    age int
)

func main() {
    rows, err := sql.Open("mysql", "dbaccess:dbaccess@/dbaccess")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    rows, err = sql.Query("select * from people where id = ?", 1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&id, &name)
        if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Println(id, name)
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
}

}
```

But I get the error:

```
20: undefined: sql.Query
```

I tried to put a colon before = but then got an error:

```
20: no new variables on left side of :=
```

what am I missing? I know there are other errors in the code, but just trying to debug/learn as I go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_DB_Query). `Open` returns a "pointer to a database", `Query` is a method that uses this pointer (and not sql). So you need to do something like this:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "dbaccess:dbaccess@/dbaccess")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
defer rows.Close()

rows, err := db.Query("select * from people where id = ?", 1)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
defer rows.Close()
```